How can I sign out from the home page and go to the login page in .net .MAUI?
I am a .net MAUI beginner and I found myself stuck inside the HomePAge and I can't log out and go to the LoginPage.
I am trying to add a toolbar (hamburger-menu) where i can find the log out button. I hope that you can help me to solve my problem.

There is no inherent concept of "login" or "logout" in MAUI.  It depends on what auth method you are using.  If you just want to add an option to the hamburger menu, you need to show us the code you have so far and what exact problem you are having with it.

The problem is that Ithe hamburger menu didn't work fo me

please post that code and explain what "didn't work" means.  Read [ask] for guidance on writing an on-topic question
